# DOMDocument missing HTML tags

Tags: php, domdocument

I play an online game called Tribalwars, and am now trying to write a report parser. A typical report looks like this:

https://enp2.tribalwars.net/public_report/395cf3cc373a3b8873c20fa018f1aa07

I have two functions adapted from php.net that now look as follows:

```
function has_child($p)
{
    if ($p->hasChildNodes())
    {
        foreach ($p->childNodes as $c)
        {
            if ($c->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function show_node($x)
{
    foreach ($x->childNodes as $p)
    {
        if ($this->has_child($p))
        {
            $this->show_node($p);
        }
        elseif ($p->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
            if (trim($p->nodeValue) !== '')
            {
                $temp = explode("\n", $p->nodeValue);
                if (count($temp) == 1)
                {
                    $this->reportdata[] = trim($temp[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach ($temp as $k => $v)
                    {
                        if (trim($v) !== '')
                        {
                            $this->reportdata[] = trim($v);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It returns the result in the following format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MASHAD (27000) attacks 40-014-Devil...
    [1] => May 11, 2016  19:27:12
    [2] => MASHAD has won
    [3] => Attacker's luck
    ...
    [76] => Espionage
    [77] => Resources scouted:
    [78] => Building
    ...
    [112] => Haul:
    [113] => .
    [114] => .
    [115] => .
    [116] => .
    [117] => .
    ...
    [120] => https://enp2.tribalwars.net/public_report/395...
)
```

For the most part this works, but some data goes lost in the parsing. If you look at the report at the link, you will see "Resources scouted" and "Haul" sections. Both these sections contain `<span>`, incidentally. For some reason those two sections are missing in the array that the functions return. (See array item 77 and array items 113 - 118). Lines 113 - 118 just show the `.` of the strangely formatted number, line 77 just has nothing.

In the function where I call the `show_node()` function, I do a little bit of processing to throw out unnecessary DOM code that is not needed:

```
$temp = explode('<h1>Publicized report</h1>', $report[0]['reportdata']);
$rep = $temp[1];
$temp = explode('For quick copy and paste', $rep);
$rep = '<report>' . $temp[0] . '</report>';
$x = new DOMDocument();
$x->loadHTML($rep);
$this->show_node($x->getElementsByTagName('report')->item(0));
```

If I do an output of `$rep` before calling the `show_node()` function, the information I need for `Haul` and `Resources scouted` is present.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if DOMDocument has a limit on how deep in the document it goes to or something. Either that or the recursive code above is wrong. I have therefore identified the piece of code that is not being parsed, saw that it is well-formed and then went on to remove its children that I do not need with `str_replace()`, and that ended up getting the values in my array. Anyway, this problem is now resolved.